# How to add tooltip to Angular material stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to add tooltip on hover for each steppers. But `matTooltip` doesn't seem to work with `mat-step`.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
  <mat-step label="Home" matTooltip="Info about the Home">
    </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Select" matTooltip="Info about the Select">
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Graph" matTooltip="Info about the Graph">
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Test" matTooltip="Info about the Test">
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-dem?file=app%2Fdemo%2Fdemo.component.html)

Is there any way to make it work? If not `material tooltip` any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I wasn't able to display the tooltip with `matTooltip`.

I used [ng2-tooltip-directive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tooltip-directive)

But it works only with label not with the stepper.

```
 <mat-step  state="step">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>
             <div tooltip="Tooltip">Test</div>
          </ng-template>
 </mat-step>
```

Comment: I  am hiding inactive step labels  & showing only active and selected step labels. so I can't add tooltip to the labels

Comment: What if the step is disabled (pointer-events: none; cursor: not-allowed;)? any idea for that?

Answer (score 2):

Import **MatTooltipModule** in app.module.ts

And write **MatTooltipModule** in import section.

```
import { MatToolbarModule, MatCardModule, MatStepperModule, MatButtonModule,MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Change your code to below

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
<mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
        <div matTooltip="Info about the Home">Home
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-step>
<mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
        <div matTooltip="Info about the Select">Select
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-step>

<mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
        <div matTooltip="Info about the Graph">Graph
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-step>


<mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
        <div matTooltip="Info about the Test">Test
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-step>
```

Comment: If you see my `Stackblitz` demo link I am hiding inactive step labels. If I add tooltip to the labels I wont be able to show for those steps

Comment: I have checked in  your Stackblitz demo, you need to import MatTooltipModule.

Comment: Yeah. It will be displayed for only active steps. I have commented out the html you shared in the stackblitz. You can remove the comment and check. It will not work for inactive steps

Answer (score 0):

I created a mouse over event to put my values in each stepper using matTooltip.
When I active the mouse over, I just return the name.

HTML:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper >
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit" let-index="index">
      <mat-icon (mouseover)="getTooltip(index)" [matTooltip]="mouseOverTooltip">create</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="done" let-index="index">
      <mat-icon (mouseover)="getTooltip(index)" [matTooltip]="mouseOverTooltip">done</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="number" let-index="index">
      <span (mouseover)="getTooltip(index)" [matTooltip]="mouseOverTooltip">{{index + 1}}</span>
    </ng-template>
    <!-- Your steppers  -->
    <mat-step [editable]="true" >
        <ng-template matStepLabel >
            <div >
              .
            </div>
          </ng-template>
    </mat-step>
    <!-- ... -->
</mat-horizontal-stepper>



JS::
 
getTooltip(index){
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        this.mouseOverTooltip =  'Tooltip1';
        break
      case 1:
        this.mouseOverTooltip =  'Tooltip2';
        break
      case 2:
        this.mouseOverTooltip =  'Tooltip3';
        break
      case 3:
        this.mouseOverTooltip =  'Tooltip4';
        break
      case 4:
        this.mouseOverTooltip =  'Tooltip5';
        break
    }
  }
```